# How do I overcome - "An error has occured - please retry your request"?

Tags: internet-explorer-10

Windows 7: I have recently upgraded from IE 9 to IE 10.  The problem(s) occur when I try to interact with sites; for example I want to place an up vote here in SuperUser.

Another problem was I could not post in Facebook.

Workarounds: a) Use Mozilla.  b) Use another machine with IE10!

Suspicion: It's something to do with my Google Toolbar.  That said it was in the same state as when I used IE 9.

N.B. This is a screenshot of the problem, and not an answer!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable all IE add-ons (including Google Toolbar) and check if the problem persists. If it's fixed, try enabling add-ons one by one and check which one causes the problem.

Also try removing cookies. If you have 3rd-party cookies disabled, enable them.

Comment: Thank you.  Is it just me, or is it a common effect, just writing down the question helps formulate the answer.  In this case I knew in my heart I should disable the Toolbar, having someone confirm pushed me to do it.  Eureka, Disabling then Enabling seems to have cured the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have found recently that simply clicking on the X and continuing solves the problem.  The dialog box, or 'Up Vote' then accepts my command when I click on it a second time.